# andorid Recycler View with lists are overlapping each other

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-volley

Here is the image

[image]

Please ask me more for more information

```
public class ProductFragment extends Fragment  implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,ProductAdaptor.ProductAdapterListener {
private static final String TAG = ProductFragment.class.getSimpleName();
/** The default socket timeout in milliseconds */
public static final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS = 2500;

/** The default number of retries */
public static final int DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES = 1;

/** The default backoff multiplier */
public static final float DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT = 1f;
private ProductAdaptor adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private VolleySingleton volleySingleton;
// To store all the products
private static  List<ProductInfo> productsList=new ArrayList<>();
ProductAdaptor.ProductAdapterListener listener;
 //Progress dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

public static ProductFragment newInstance() {
    return new ProductFragment();
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    listener=this;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_fragment,container,false);
    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.productList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    pDialog.setMessage("Fetching products...");
    showpDialog();
    volleySingleton=VolleySingleton.getInstance();
    requestQueue=volleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, AppConfig.URL_PRODUCTS, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    //hide the progress dialog
                    hidepDialog();
                    adapter=new ProductAdaptor(getActivity(),parseJSONOResponse(response),listener);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // hide the progress dialog
                    hidepDialog();

                }
            });
    // Wait 20 seconds and don't retry more than once

    jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
             DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS,
            DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);



    return layout;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);



}
public boolean PerformSearch(String searchString){

    //adapter.getFilter().filter(searchString);
    return true;

}

public void setDataSet(List<ProductInfo> newDataSet){
    productsList = newDataSet;
    adapter=new ProductAdaptor(MyApplication.getAppContext(),productsList,this);
    recyclerView.swapAdapter(adapter, false);
    //new way of filtering data

}

private List<ProductInfo> parseJSONOResponse(JSONObject response){
    try {

        JSONArray products = response.getJSONArray("products");
        for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject product = (JSONObject) products
                    .get(i);

            String id = product.getString("product_id");
            String name = product.getString("name");
            String description = product
                    .getString("description");
            String image = AppConfig.URL_IMAGE_PRODUCTS + product.getString("image");
            BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(product
                    .getString("price"));

            ProductInfo p = new ProductInfo(id, name, description,
                    image, price);

            productsList.add(p);

        }
        return productsList;
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return productsList;

}
@Override
public void onAddToCartPressed(ProductInfo product) {
    CartHandler cartHandler=new CartHandler(MyApplication.getAppContext());

    if (cartHandler.getProductsInCartCount()==0) {
        cartHandler.addProductInCart(product);
        Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(),
                product.getName() + " added to cart!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else{
        ProductInfo temp=cartHandler.getProductInCart(Integer.parseInt(product.getId()));
        if (temp!=null){

            cartHandler.updateProduct(product);
            Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(),
                    product.getName() + " added to cart!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else
        {

            cartHandler.addProductInCart(product);
                   Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(),
                   product.getName() + " added to cart!",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


}
private void showpDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing()){
        pDialog.show();
    }
}

private void hidepDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}


@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
   // final List<ProductInfo> filteredModelList = filter(productsList, query);
   // adapter.animateTo(filteredModelList);
    //recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
    return true;
}

private List<ProductInfo> filter(List<ProductInfo> models, String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();

    final List<ProductInfo> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ProductInfo model : models) {
        final String text = model.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(query)) {
            filteredModelList.add(model);
        }
    }
    return filteredModelList;
}
```

}

**Product adaptor**

```
public class ProductAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdaptor.ProductViewHolder>{
    //implements Filterable {

private final LayoutInflater inflator;
private final List<ProductInfo> products;
private Context context;
private ProductAdapterListener listener;
ImageLoader imageLoader = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getImageLoader();
//private List<ProductInfo> BackupProducts= Collections.emptyList();
ProductInfo current;

public ProductAdaptor(Context context, List<ProductInfo> data, ProductAdapterListener listener){
    inflator= LayoutInflater.from(context);
    products=data;
    this.context=context;
    this.listener=listener;
    //BackupProducts=data;
}

@Override
public ProductAdaptor.ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_product, parent, false);
    ProductViewHolder holder=new ProductViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductAdaptor.ProductViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    current=products.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(current.getName());
    holder.icon.setImageUrl(current.getImage(), imageLoader);
    holder.price.setText("Price: Rs. " + current.getPrice());
    holder.description.setText(current.getDescription());
    holder.add_Cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            products.get(position).setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(holder.etQuantity.getText().toString()));
            listener.onAddToCartPressed(products.get(position));
        }
    });
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Reading Position", "" + current.getId());
            Intent base=new Intent(context, Products.class);
            base.putExtra("product_id", Integer.parseInt(products.get(position).getId()));
            base.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            context.startActivity(base);
        }
    });

}
public void setData(List<ProductInfo> list){
    products.clear();
    products.addAll(list);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
/*
public void flushFilter(){
    products.clear();
    products.addAll(BackupProducts);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}*/

public void animateTo(List<ProductInfo> models) {
    applyAndAnimateRemovals(models);
    applyAndAnimateAdditions(models);
    applyAndAnimateMovedItems(models);
}

private void applyAndAnimateRemovals(List<ProductInfo> newModels) {
    for (int i = products.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final ProductInfo model = products.get(i);
        if (!newModels.contains(model)) {
            removeItem(i);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(List<ProductInfo> newModels) {
    for (int i = 0, count = newModels.size(); i < count; i++) {
        final ProductInfo model = newModels.get(i);
        if (!products.contains(model)) {
            addItem(i, model);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateMovedItems(List<ProductInfo> newModels) {
    for (int toPosition = newModels.size() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
        final ProductInfo model = newModels.get(toPosition);
        final int fromPosition = products.indexOf(model);
        if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
            moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }
    }
}

public ProductInfo removeItem(int position) {
    final ProductInfo model = products.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    return model;
}

public void addItem(int position, ProductInfo model) {
    products.add(position, model);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    final ProductInfo model = products.remove(fromPosition);
    products.add(toPosition, model);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return products.size();
}
/*
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    //flushFilter();
    return new CardFilter(this,BackupProducts);
}
*/


public interface ProductAdapterListener {
    void onAddToCartPressed(ProductInfo product);
}


class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView title;
    NetworkImageView icon;
    TextView price;
    TextView description;
    LinearLayout add_Cart;
    TextView etQuantity;

    public ProductViewHolder(final View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        icon =(NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productImage);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productName);
        price= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productPrice);
        description=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productDescription);
        add_Cart= (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_cart);
        etQuantity= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quanity);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

These are both of the classes for this Product list please if you need more information please comment

Thanks in advance

There are two classes and those take products from my json and  assign it to view holder

Comment: show your adapter and recycler initialization

Comment: show some codes please

Comment: show the code; without it we just can guess !

Comment: Isn't the inner class i.e., ProductViewHolder should be declared static

Comment: i dont know will you specify why

Comment: i've tried static but its doesnt work

Comment: guys please help me i'm on the clock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused because of overlapping fragments and i was starting the fragment like this

```
fragment=ProductFragment.newInstance();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.productFragment,fragment )
                    .commit();
```

so making it simply

```
fragment=ProductFragment.newInstance();
```

solved my problem.

Thanks guys for help @MohammadAllam

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue too after many search i fixed it whit update gradle dependencies i think its happened because one of old android dependencies.